# Compiler error cs1061 visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added a button to my form and get error cs1061.I already put method protected.
 Error  CS1061  'Cos' does not contain a definition for 'button1_Click' and no extension method 'button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'Cos' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   projectbaze D:\Anul3\baze de   date\projectbaze\projectbaze\Cos.Designer.cs 64  Active

```
namespace projectbaze
 {
public partial class ptlaptopuri : UserControl
{


    public ptlaptopuri()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var context = new DataClasses2DataContext();
        var alex = from emp in context.Produses
                   where (emp.Nume == "Asus" && emp.Categorie_id == 1)
                   select emp;
        foreach (var a in alex)
        {
            Cos fm2 = new Cos();
            fm2.AddGridViewRows(a.Nume.ToString(),a.Pret.ToString(),"1");
        }
    }
```

and

```
  namespace projectbaze
  {
public partial class Cos : Form
{
    public Cos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

           public void AddGridViewRows(string Nume, string Pret, string Cantitate)
    {
        // Add rows to grid view.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Nume, Pret, Cantitate);

        // Refresh the grid
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You obviously tried to add a event handler called `button1_Click` to a control in `Cos` via designer. But `Cos` does not contain such a method, you declared that method in `ptlaptopuri`, not in `Cos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you deleted a button that originally resided on your "Cos" form. Go into Cos.Designer.cs and delete line 64 and run your project. That should fix it.